# Pass keystrokes to Sublime snippet with AutoPair on?

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

I am writing a new def snippet for Python that adds a prepopuluted docstring from the variable names. My regex is currently choking on any character that SublimeText Auto-pairs: **()""''[]{}**.

Is is possible to retain the auto-pair functionality while still passing the keystroke information into a snippet? My regex currently expects balanced expressions, however I could make do with even a single keystroke passed.

The snippet below works great when *"auto_match_enabled": false* in user key bindings, and fails when set to true. Any direction is much appreciated!

Sublime formatting:

```
<snippet>
    <tabTrigger>def</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>Function</description>

    <content><![CDATA[def ${1:function}($2) -> (${3:None}):
    """
    ${4:Heading}

    ${5:Description}

    Args:
${2/(?(DEFINE)(?'quote'(?:((?<q>["'])(?:(?!\k<q>|\\).)*(?:\\.(?:(?!\k<q>|\\).)*)*\k<q>))))(?(DEFINE)(?'delim'(?:,\s?)))(?(DEFINE)(?'paren'(?:(\((?>[^()]|(?&paren))*\)))))(?(DEFINE)(?'brac'(?:(\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?&brac))*\]))))(?(DEFINE)(?'curl'(?:(\{(?>[^\{\}]|(?&curl))*\}))))(?(DEFINE)(?'equal'(?:=\s?(?:(?P>quote)|(?>\w+)|(?P>brac)|(?P>curl)|(?P>paren))(?:(?P>delim)|\z))))(?'var'(?>\w+))((?>:\s\w+)(?:(?P>equal)|(?P>delim)|\z)|\s?(?P>equal)|(?P>delim)|\z)/\t\t$+{var}: \n/g}

    Returns:
        ${6:Return description with}

    Tests:
        >>> ${7:2+2}
        ${8:4}

    """

    ${0:pass}]]></content>
</snippet>
```

### Regex example

$2 (Input string):

```
x, y: int, z: str="String can have \"quotes\" inside", hah = [1, 2, 3, 4], l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Args (Output substitution):

```
    x: 
    y: 
    z: 
    hah: 
    l:
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a direct answer to this, but do have a workaround: disabling the auto-pair key bindings when in this scope: meta.function.parameters.python

[Full walkthrough on Github](https://github.com/tbenst/Sublime-Python-Snippets/blob/master/README.md).

I will leave this open for a few more days in case anyone has a better answer than this hack!